# Send a request to Asp.net WebService using Angular

Tags: asp.net, angular, web-services, asmx

I executed a WebService using Postman and it's executed correctly. And now i want to send a request to the WebService using Angular

Here is the Asp.net Web Service

This is the code for my WebService

```
public class Temperature : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        [WebMethod]
        public double Farenheit(double celsius)
        {
            return  (celsius * 9) / 5 + 32;
        }
        [WebMethod]
        public double Celsius(double fahrenheit)
        {
            return (fahrenheit - 32) * 5 / 9;
        }
    }
```

And this is the screenshot on how i send a request using PostMan and it's working as expected

[Screenshot for Calling the WebService using Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47lbs.png)

Here is the code for the Angular

```
const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type':  'text/xml',

      })
    };


this.http.post('https://localhost:44389/Temperature.asmx/Celsius', '50',  httpOptions)
    .subscribe(res => {
      console.log('Data: ' + res);
    })
```

And this is the error I'm receiving

Error

```
"System.InvalidOperationException: Request format is invalid: text/xml.
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.ReadParameters()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.CoreProcessRequest()
"
```

Message

```
Http failure response for https://localhost:44389/Temperature.asmx/Celsius: 500 OK
```

Name

```
"HttpErrorResponse"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your  **'Content-Type':  'text/xml'** to  **'Content-Type':  'application/json'**

Comment: Thank you it worked, But the error is different now. But i think that solved my problem. Thank you

Comment: @AngularLearner, I'm glad I could help. If you don't find the solution then don't hesitate to ask. Good luck

Comment: Good day. May i know why I'm receiving an error with the code right now:

error: Cannot convert object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]'

Comment: @AngularLearner, I suggest you are sending an integer to a method that needs a object like {'hello',some object}, for more details I think you better ask it in a new thread and upload some of your code

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

setHttpHeader() {
 const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Accept', 'application/json').set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
let options = { headers: headers };
return options;
}


this.http.post('https://localhost:44389/Temperature.asmx/Celsius', '50', this.setHttpHeader())
.subscribe(res => {
  console.log('Data: ' + res);
})
```